# Select columns with specific value in R

Tags: r

I have the following problem within R:

I'm working with a huge matrix. Some of the columns contain  the value 'zero', which leads to problems during my further work.

Hence, I want to identify the columns, which contain at least one value of 'zero'.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a big matrix then this would be probably faster than an apply solution:
`mat[,colSums(mat==0)<0.5]`

Answer (score 0):

lets say your matrix is called x,

```
x = matrix(runif(300), nrow=10)
```

to get the indices of the columns that have at least 1 zero:

```
ix = apply(x, MARGIN=2, function(col){any(col==0)})
```